# Compare a new line with the last line in a TXT file

Tags: android, string, gps, compare

I have an app that uses the GPS to find your location, then it writes the location to a txt file

```
try
        {
            OutputStreamWriter fout= new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("datosgps.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
                fout.append( latitude+longitude+"\n");

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aviso.class);
            startActivity(intent);

                fout.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Ficheros", "Error");
        }
```

Inside the txt file I have this:

```
 Latitud: 49.650 Longitud: 2.931
 Latitud: 49.655 Longitud: 2.939
 Latitud: 49.656 Longitud: 2.939
 Latitud: 49.657 Longitud: 2.939
 Latitud: 49.657 Longitud: 2.939
```

One below the other.

Every 2 minutes, it writes the NEW location,
What can I do to check if the NEW line is the SAME that the LAST line?

for example, I want it to read

Latitud: 49.656 Longitud: 2.939

and then write the new location

Latitud: 49.657 Longitud: 2.939

**Check if they are same**

if not, do nothing

read the LAST

Latitud: 49.657 Longitud: 2.939

and the NEW location

Latitud: 49.657 Longitud: 2.939

If are equal do something

Any suggestion will be appreciated

EDITED

```
What do you mean.. something like this?

        String newdata = latitude+longitude;
    if((newdata.equals(lastdata){

    //DO SOMETHING
    }
          try
                {


                    OutputStreamWriter fout= new OutputStreamWriter(

openFileOutput("datosgps.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
                fout.append( latitude+longitude+"\n");

                fout.close();
    String lastdata = latitude+longitude;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("Ficheros", "Error");
            }
```

Now I have the last data in a String , and in the .txt I have one line such as:

Latitude: 43.4556 Longitude :34.333

in 6 seconds, it will write the new data and it have to compare

newdata with lastdata but the first time it runs, lastadata doesn't exist , then it crashes.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just hold on to the last values you wrote (store them in `last_latitude` and `last_longitude`) and then simply check if you new values are the same as these before deciding to write?

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look. thank you for your time